# In App Purchase How to check if item purchased

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase

hi there i have followed a tutorial online for in app purchase and have gotten it to work perfect but the only problem is when i reopen the app i have to restore the purchase to make is display again

how would i check when that app loads that the item was purchased and can display the purchased content

here is the link for the online tutorial - http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial

if anybody could give me some pointers that would fantastic

Answer (score 0):

You can store those data in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or in the [keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) and check in those whether the user has already purchased the item or not

To Store in the NSUserDefaults:

when user made your in App then set value in NSUserDefaults like this

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isPurchase"];

        [userDefaults synchronize];
```

and when you starts the app you can check whether the user has already purchased the in-app like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if(![userDefaults boolForKey:@"isPurchase"])
        {

          // Unlock your features code comes here
        }
```

And I strongly recommend you to go through this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)

Comment: its better to save this kind of data in keychain.

Comment: or you can use Parse to store data in the cloud (to avoid having IAPs hacked by people who jailbreak)